# Pandas Reading CSV and sending to Excel One Entry Behind

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv, tkinter

The program is supposed to take user data via tkinter widgets and then send the data to a csv file. The csv file is read and transformed to a dataFrame which is sent to excel. The program works except that it is always one entry behind the current. If I enter 5 entries, only 4 show up in excel.

Here is a code snippet of the method that when a button is pressed sends the data to csv to dataframe and then to excel.

```
def enterbtn(df:pd.DataFrame):
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    x = open('storage.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(x)
    row = [date,temperature]
    writer.writerow(row)
    df = pd.read_csv("storage.csv")
    df.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    #window.destroy()
    print(df)
```

I tried to make a separate method for sending to excel but it through an error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to save the temporary .csv file? Can you do something like the following?

```
def enterbtn(df:pd.DataFrame):
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = [date, temperature] 
    df.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    #window.destroy()
    print(df)
```

Comment: so when I ran that it throws a bunch of errors, I do not understand all of them. The problem I had with using the loc() method is that when it sends data to the excel file it does not append the data, instead the first row is continually overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the CSV file to make the change effective before reading it:

```py
def enterbtn(df:pd.DataFrame):
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    x = open('storage.csv', 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(x)
    row = [date,temperature]
    writer.writerow(row)
    x.close()  # close the file to save the change
    df = pd.read_csv("storage.csv")
    df.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    #window.destroy()
    print(df)
```